# Two Cursor Bug in Ubuntu 20.04 in 125% resolution

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, display-resolution, cursor, ideapad

I am using Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 with ubuntu 20.4 (GNOME and don't suggest me other DE please), with 125% resolution, but getting the issue of two cursors after logging in. How am I supposed to solve this issue?

[image]